# Pointing IFTTT Recipe to a different Instagram Account

Tags: if-this-then-that, instagram

I am a teacher and have set up an IFTTT account to automatically post our classroom Instagram account photos to our classroom Facebook page.  IFTTT automatically is connecting to my *personal* Instagram account.  It let's me choose the classroom Facebook page [which is connected to my personal Facebook], but I cannot find a way to change the Instagram account from my personal to my classroom account.

Comment: If I recall, IFTTT only lets you set up one of each type of account. Facebook pages are a bit of a different beast. I think to do what you want you'll need a different IFTTT account or for your IFTTT account to use the classroom Instagram account.

Answer (score 1):

It will be a ten minute project but Flickr still supports what you want so if you register Flickr, or several other IFTTT file-hosting services, you can still post to your class instagram. I hope I understand well enough and that this helps, but here is what I would try:

Your Primary IFTTT Account:
If
{New Instagram Photo}
Then
{Save Photo to [SomeServiceFolderLikeFlickrFolderX]}

Your New Classroom IFTTT Account:
If
{NewFilOorImageLikeOnFlickrOrFTPRSS}
Then
{Post to ClassroomFacebookWall}

So essentially you need to set up another IFTTT account, link it to the classroom IFTTT, then set triggers in your personal account that transpose the image to your new IFTTT which will be linked to the correct page, whereat you can post.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation and this seems to have worked for me.

Go into the Instagram account that you do not want used and click the Edit Profile button. Revoke Access for IFTTT on the Authorized Applications tab.

On the IFTTT page, go to Channels and disconnect the Instagram channel. Go to Recipes and create a new recipe using Instagram. It should now ask you to authorize the application again. If you are logged into the correct Instagram account, accept this account. If not, click the "Not" link and log into the correct account.